# Which CloudFoundry buildpack supports the MEAN stack?

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I have an application built with the MEAN stack - node express mongo and angular. Which buildpack should I use when I deploy my app? Is there a buildpack that is specific to the MEAN stack or should I just use the node.js buildpack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cloud Foundry, a buildpack represents the runtime you are using for your application. For developing on Cloud Foundry with the MEAN stack, you should use the community Node.js buildpack. You can then use Angular for your front end and connect a Mondo-DBaaS instance as a service to support this stack.

Comment: HI Jake, just to verify ,in this case the only buildpack which I should use is node.js?  https://github.com/cloudfoundry/buildpack-nodejs.git

Comment: That's right, Mark. The buildpack stages your Node.js application, which in-turn handles the "MEA" part of your MEAN stack.

Node.js handles your front-end frameworks and dependencies in the MEAN stack.

Comment: Yes, Mark, that is the primary community node.js buildpack. However, there are other CF vendor buildpacks for node as well